# Transfering UK pension to AU super

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, pension

I will be re-locating to the UK in the near future with the intention of returning to Australia after 3-4 years.

If I make contributions toward a UK pension, will it be possible to transfer funds to an Australian super? and which organization is best placed to provide additional information regarding this?